# crontab error - SSMTP - 553 5.7.1 Sender address rejected: not owned by user

Tags: cron, email, root, ssmtp

As root, I installed ssmtp and I configured the `/etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf` as follows:

```
# Sender email address
root=myemail@domain.com

# Destination SMTP server and port
mailhub=mail.domain.com:587

# Username and password
AuthUser=myemail@domain.com
AuthPass=password

# Sender domain
rewriteDomain=domain.com

# Machine's hostname
hostname=mail.domain.com:587

# Allow set From name in each email
FromLineOverride=YES

UseSTARTTLS=YES
UseTLS=YES
```

I also configured revaliases in `/etc/ssmtp/revaliases` adding the following row:

`root:myemail@domain.com:mail.domain.com:587`

I set a cron running `crontab -e` and added the rows (just to test it's running):

```
MAILTO=myemail@domain.com
* * * * * echo "this is a test"
```

If I run `grep cron /var/log/syslog` I see the following error:

```
cron[2704289]: sendmail: RCPT TO:<myemail@domain.com> (553 5.7.1 <root@domain.com>: Sender address rejected: not owned by user myemail@domain.com)
```

`myemail@domain.com` is changed in `root@domain.com`and I cannot find a solution.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have inverted the meaning of `FromLineOverride`. Here with it set to `yes` you are declaring that the sender is allowed to override the settings defined in `ssmtp.conf`, and this is why the sender is ending up as `root`.

Switch that setting off (`no`) and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thank you so much. I confused the correct value of `FromLineOverride`.